# How can I log the value of a variable sent in an HTTP Request sent from JMeter, if the value was first read in from a csv file

Tags: jmeter

I would like to read the exact value of a variable I use to pass through an HTTP Request.  I first read in many values of variables using the CSV Data Set Config.  For the username, it is in the form of an email address.  So, I have a variable called "email" in the Data Set Config.  In the actual HTTP Request, for "name", I call it "username".  For the "Value" field for this same "username", I added a time() function to it like this so I would end up creating unique users in my tests:

```
${email}${__time()
```

When I view the "Request" in a View Results Tree, I can see my parameter is listed correctly:

```
    username=email1%40email.com1390854377360
```

I do not care if this is correct in real world terms.  I already know that is not a valid email.  That is ok for now.

What I want to know is how can I log that email that I just created on the fly?  I would like to not have to pull in the whole request every time also and then use some type of Regular Expression extractor.  It just seems like there should be an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 2 ways,

1. Beanshell Pre/Post processors : you can write custom code in which you can log all your variables in some custom log file
2. Simple data writer : you can configure it and check save url,save field names,save response data field checkboxes that will give you complete data but in that later postprocessing on result file is required to get all usernames (email in your case).

first approach is easier and allows you create your own logging format(easy to retrieve and use somewhere else).
second approach is somewhat tedious and requires post processing.

Comment: For the logging, I successfully used a BeanShell PostProcessor with this in the Script: String email = vars.get("email"); fs = new FileOutputStream( "log.log", true); ps = new PrintStream( fs ); ps.println( "Email address: " + email ); ps.close(); fs.close();  I still have to figure out how to add the time to the end of the email before I log this email.  I tried a BeanShell PreProcessor, under the same HTTP Request as this BeanShell PostProcessor was located.  But, the email never seems to be updated using: String email = vars.get( "email" );  vars.put ( "email", email + ${__time()} );